# Run a script when device is connected via USB C

Tags: macos, usb

How can I run a specific program when a new device has been plugged into a USB C port?

Comment: As for the first question, have a look at [Event Scripts](https://www.mousedown.net/software/EventScripts.html)

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it should work.